# problem regarding self registration of wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, user-registration, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to create account with self user registration in wso2 identity server i get form which asks for username of registration after that I get below error in wso2 identity server logs.
any help appreciated how can i resolve this issue?

```
 [2021-04-09 11:43:46,914] [bfbad83a-f5d2-493a-8ead-66389c76726b] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/accountrecoveryendpoint].[jsp]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.client.SelfRegistrationMgtClientException: Error while retrieving data from https://localhost:9446/api/identity/consent-mgt/v1.0/consents/purposes?group=SELF-SIGNUP&groupType=SYSTEM. Found http status HTTP/1.1 500
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.client.SelfRegistrationMgtClient.executeGet(SelfRegistrationMgtClient.java:186)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.client.SelfRegistrationMgtClient.getPurposes(SelfRegistrationMgtClient.java:87)
    at org.apache.jsp.self_002dregistration_002dwith_002dverification_jsp._jspService(self_002dregistration_002dwith_002dverification_jsp.java:296)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


[2021-04-09 12:30:10,246] [0cbb334b-2886-46cc-8ea1-70f232fae387] ERROR 
{org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]. 
[/accountrecoveryendpoint].[signup.do]} - Servlet.service() for servlet 
[signup.do] in context with path [/accountrecoveryendpoint] threw exception 
[An exception occurred processing [/self-registration-with-verification.jsp] 
at line [127]

124:
125:         }
126:     }
127:     String purposes = 
selfRegistrationMgtClient.getPurposes(user.getTenantDomain(), 
consentPurposeGroupName,
128:             consentPurposeGroupType);
129:     boolean hasPurposes = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(purposes);
130:     Claim[] claims = new Claim[0];


      Stacktrace:] with root cause 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.client.SelfRegistrationMgtClientException: Error while retrieving data from 
 https://localhost:9446/api/identity/consent-mgt/v1.0/consents/purposes?group=SELF-SIGNUP&groupType=SYSTEM. Found http status HTTP/1.1 500
```

Comment: What is the version of IS that you use?

Comment: is version is 5.10.0